# csv +php или несите огнетушитель

Tags: php, csv

Ребят кидаю данные в csv файл 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Получается в одну колонку, а надо в несколько ,разделитель не работает((

Comment: Что в самом файле csv написано текстом? чем вы его открываете?

Comment: @coder675 текстом там тоже в одну колонку. Из кода это ясно, как божий день.

Comment: а где переход на новую строку? вы в блокноте открывали свой файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode(',', $v['id'])` - **бессмысленная операция** (как и две последующие). Все что нужно сделать:

```
foreach ($key as $v1) {
    fputcsv($fp, $v1);
    // или судя по `[company]['id']`
    fputcsv($fp, [$v1['id'], $v1['name'], $v1['company']['id']]);

}
```

На будущее - научитесь вставлять код в вопрос **текстом**, а не картинками.

Comment: Спасибо,все верно +1

Comment: Если вопрос решает проблему - вы можете __принять__ его, чтобы последующим посетителям было понятно что делать в подобной проблеме.